# EF Code First - Eager Loading and Filtering Subclass Properties (Inheritance)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

I have the following classes (overly simplified):

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Content
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Image : Content
{
    public bool Private { get; set; }
    public Person Author { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get all the `Tags` where the `Content` is an `Image` and the `Image` is not `Private` (while eagerly loading a property of `Image`). Example that attempts to do this but doesn't work:

```
var tags = context.Tags
    .Include("Content.Author")
    .Include("Person")
    .Where(t => !((Image)t.Content).Private);
```

I get the following errors:

> Unable to cast the type 'Content' to type 'Image'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

And with the `Where` clause removed:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Content' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Author'.

What kind of query and/or model schema change would I need to be able to accomplish this approach?

Comment: Not an answer but try using your eager loading with Lambda includes.
Add the using statement System.Data.Entity

and your Include should be context.Tags.Include(t => t.Content.Author).Include(t => t.Person)

Comment: @Patrick I get compiler errors attempting to use any lambda Include() using EF 5.0. Is there something else I need to be able to use those?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on your project, add reference, then in the popup dialogue from the Assemblies menu select framework, do a search for System.Data and include it from there, see if that works. - http://i.imgur.com/zr9kr70.png

Comment: @PatrickMagee I was able to get the lambda to work, by: `using System.Data.Entity;` Unfortunately, I got the same error as before: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Content' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Author'. This also doesn't solve the `Where` clause issue.

Comment: Could it be trying to cast to system.drawing.image ?

Comment: Do you need to add .Include("Content")  ?

Comment: @kirsteng It's casting to [ProjectName].Common.Models.Image, so no. Also, if you include "Object.PropertyObject", EF automatically includes "Object".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the filter in the `Where` clause the following way:

```
.Where(t => t.Content is Image && !(t.Content as Image).Private)
```

However, the bigger problem is the `Include` part. The `Author` property only exists for the derived type `Image` but `Include` will try to load the base type `Content` (which doesn't have an `Author` property) because that's the type of the navigation property `Content` in `Tag`. You just can't use `Include` here.

You can try to rewrite the query as a projection:

```
var tags = context.Tags
    .Where(t => t.Content is Image && !(t.Content as Image).Private)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Tag = t,
        Image = t.Content as Image, // possibly this line is not needed
        Author = (t.Content as Image).Author,
        Person = t.Person
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.Tag)
    .ToList();
```

As long as you don't disable change tracking (with `AsNoTracking` for example) EF should put the object graph together automatically so that the loaded tags have a populated `Content`, `Content.Author` and `Person` property (*as if* you had loaded the navigation properties with `Include`).

BTW: The feature to include navigation properties of a derived type is requested [here on UserVoice](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1249289-include-property-of-derived-classes). It's not exactly the same as your situation, but in the comment section is a request even for your scenario.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for the answer and for the link to the UserVoice feature.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the class definitions to something like...

```
class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Content
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Image : Content
{
  public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }   
  public virtual Person Author { get; set; }
}

class Tag
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public Content Content { get; set; }
public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Private doesnt seem like a good name for a property  because it conflicts with the public or private declaration.